# List View Android (Remove Radio Buttons)?

Tags: android, android-layout

I had got this code from somewhere and edited it. Can you tell me how to remove those radio buttons from the starting items ???? I am getting radio buttons at the right of all the list items. I dont Want that ... There is NO XML file.

```
package com.example.diseasedetection;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Desc extends ListActivity {String[] trekloc =
{"VIEW INFO","","PLEASE SELECT THE DISEASE","MALARIA","CONJUNCTIVITIS","MIGRANE"
};


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getListView().setChoiceMode(1); 
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, trekloc));
}

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id)
{
Toast.makeText(this, trekloc[position] + " selected ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Intent i = new Intent("com.example.diseasedetection.Dispdesc");
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("Name", trekloc[position]); 
i.putExtras(extras); 
startActivity(i);

}   


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice
```

Use

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove getListView().setChoiceMode(1);

Replace android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice 
with
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1.